# Auto arrange unlimited number of buttons on form

Tags: c#, winforms, algorithm

I'm trying generate dynamically a bunch of buttons. The number of buttons is determined by how many pits are alive, and this is retrieved from a database.

Here is how it looks like :

[image: buttons]

Here is what I used to generate them :

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int numOf = pits.numOfPits();
    Button[] genButtons = new Button[numOf];
    int l = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < numOf; i++)
    {

        genButtons[i] = new Button();
        genButtons[i].Width = 160;
        genButtons[i].Height = 80;
        Point location = new Point((i + 1) *200,75);

        if (location.X > this.ClientSize.Width - 200)
        {
            location.X = l * 200;
            location.Y += 100;
                l++;
        }
        genButtons[i].Location = location;  
        this.Controls.Add(genButtons[i]);
    }
}
```

The problem is that it will only work for 2 rows and it is kind of hard coded. How can I improve it to support an unlimited number of buttons.

*You can ignore the limited "height" of form for the purpose of this question. I'll probably add some pagination later.*

Comment: "on the picture below" Where?

Comment: A [FlowLayoutPanel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel.aspx) can easily handle arbitrary amount of controls. Or, use [DataGriViewButtonColumn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewbuttoncolumn.aspx) if you want a datagrid

Comment: `FlowLayoutPanel` or `TableLayoutPanel`

Comment: Sry for that @Carl, now you can see her on link :)

Comment: Hmmm, do you know FlowLayoutPanel?

Comment: Hmm, havent heard of it yet, I'll search it. So, it's possible to do something like I want it with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add button controls to the [FlowLayoutPanel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).  Extend the FlowLayoutPanel to include items per page, current page, and data to implement paging.

```cs
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FlowLayoutPanel flp = new FlowLayoutPanel();
    for (int i = 0; i < pits.numOfPits(); ++i)
    {
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.Width = 160;
        btn..Height = 80; //set padding or margin to appropriate values
        flp.Controls.Add(btn);
    }
    this.Controls.Add(flp);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! You saved me hours of writing new algorithm for this!